# Stop mouseleave trigger when overing a child element

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseevent

how can I stop from firing the mouseleave trigger when hovering the .thumb sibling element .description which is positioned over by the attribute: position absolute.

I have the following js code

```
$('.thumb').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).siblings('.description').delay(100).slideDown(200);
        start_preview($(this));
    },

    mouseleave: function(e) {
        $(this).siblings('.description').stop(true, true).slideUp(200);
        clearInterval( $(this).data('timer') ); //Stops preview
    }
});
```

For the following HTML code:

```
<td><a href="/video?id=1052">
    <img class="thumb" src="path" />
    <div class="description"></div>
</a></td>
```

Comment: You have spelt "descripcion" wrong in your HTML class name

Comment: yes i've forgot to translate this part

Comment: Set mouseenter/mouseleave handler for the anchor tag, not the .thumb element

Comment: then i should set the handler to td tag or it's better to put a wrapper div

Comment: anchor tag or TD, should not really matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that instead:

```
$('.thumb').closest('td').on({ 
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).find('.description').delay(100).slideDown(200);
        start_preview($(this).find('.thumb'));
    },

    mouseleave: function(e) {
        $(this).find('.description').stop(true, true).slideUp(200);
        clearInterval( $(this).find('.thumb').data('timer') ); //Stops preview
    }
});
```

Comment: With this code mouse don't fire the trigger and description dont slideup :S

Comment: Oh, ya, you have to change code according too. I'll update answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.thumb').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).siblings('.description').delay(100).slideDown(200);
        start_preview($(this));
    },

    mouseleave: function(e) {
        var sibs = $(this).siblings('.description');
        $.each(sibs, function(i, v) {
            if ($(this).css('position') == 'absolute') {
                return false;
            } else {
                $(this).stop(true, true).slideUp(200);
                clearInterval( $(this).data('timer') ); //Stops preview
            };
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: It worked, but when I mouseleave from .thumb, .description don't slideup as it should

Comment: Try it that way. I made a change.